# Testing using TestNG Annotations 

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, testng

Can some one please help me with the usage of testing a JAVA class using annotations ( org.testng.annotations.Test) ... I am dealing with a program (written by some1 else) in which Junit is not used instead "org.testng.annotations.Test" is used of which i have no idea

Comment: http://testng.org/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely want to read the documentation on TestNG [here](http://testng.org/doc/index.html), as there are some differences from JUnit. Some of the annotations are similar, though.

Here are some highlights:

`@BeforeSuite`, `@BeforeClass`, `@BeforeTest` mark methods that will run before a test suite, before a test class, and before an individual test method, respectively (as you might expect).

`@Test` annotates a method as being a test method.

Those are the most similar to JUnit. The docs have a great explanation of the others.